# React Native FlatList keyExtractor and listKey

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have multiple questions about FlatList that I cannot answer reading the docs.

When do I need to use listKey and when keyExtractor? Sometimes, when I have siblings FlatLists I have to specify listKey in each list, as follows:

```
      renderItem = (item, index) => (<View key={item.id} />)

      <FlatList
           keyExtractor={({id}) => id}
           listKey="MusicList"
           renderItem={this.renderItem}
       />

       <FlatList
           keyExtractor={({id}) => id}
           listKey="BooksList"
       />
```

Can I have the listKey and the keyExtractor at the same time?

What I have been thinking until now is that listKey is like a keyExtractor but for lists, and that keyExtractor identify every item in a list... Is that right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[keyExtractor](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#keyextractor) is a function used to extract unique key for each item of a [FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist). And [listKey](https://reactnative.dev/docs/virtualizedlist#listkey) is a unique identifier for [VirtualizedList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/virtualizedlist). If there are multiple VirtualizedLists at the same level of nesting within another VirtualizedList, this key is necessary for virtualization to work properly.

From the example you have posted, keyExtractor is the unique identifier of each item of the FlatLists. and listKey is the identifier of each list.

Comment: And will it be neccessary to pass a key in render item if I have pass the keyExtractor to my FlatList?

Comment: No, its not necessary to pass key like <View key={item.id} /> if you are passing keyExtractor to your FlatList